If $K$ compact, then $\cup_{x \in K} \overline{B_r(x)}=A$ is compact
In class they gave the following exercise, which I haven't been able to prove.
It reads: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, given $K$ compact and $r>0$, then $A=\cup_{x \in K}\overline{B_r(x)}$ is also compact.
The teacher asked us to prove that $A$ is closed and bounded. The bounded part is easy, since $y \in A$ implies that $\operatorname {Norm}(y) \leq r + M$, where $M$ is the bound of $A$.
I'm struggling with the closed part.
I tried to do the following aproach: we want to show that any sequence, $y_k \in \overline{B_r(x_k)}$, and note $y_k \in A$, it's limit point is in $A$, because then we would finish, as closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is "closed" by sequences.
Now because {$x_k$} is a sequence in $K$, and $K$ is closed, then ${x_k}$ must converge to an $x \in K$. Then, $y_k$ converges to a point $y$, and I would like to show that $y \in \overline{B_r(x)}$. I don't know how to do that (or if it is even true).
If I'm enterily wrong, then what approach such I take?
Edit: I will continue now following your advice.
First we discuss further {$x_k$}$_k$, which is a sequence of $K$. The sequence must have a convergent subsequence, because it's in $K$, a compact. Now, let {$x_{k_n}$}$_{k_n}$ be this subsequence and {$y_{k_n}$}$_{k_n}$ it's associated one. Now we know that {$y_{k}$}$_{k}$ converges, and if it converges the convergence limit must be the same that of the subsequences (of $y$). So we will work with the subsequences to prove that $y \in \overline{B_r(x)}$.
We want to see that taking on limits as $n \to \infty$, then $d(y_{k_n},x_{k_n}) \leq r$ goes to $d(y,x) \leq r$. To do that, we note that the strict inequality preserves the limits.
Now, doing the other part is a matter of the inequality $$d(y_{k_n},x_{k_n}) \leq d(y_{k_n},y) + d(y,x) + d(x,x_{k_n})$$
which implies (if we also do it a similar approach on d(y,x)),
$$| d(y_{k_n},x_{k_n}) - d(x,y) | \leq d(y_{k_n},y) + d(x,x_{k_n})$$
and because both subsequences converge then $d(y_{k_n},x_{k_n})$ also converges, which is the same as saying that $y \in \overline{B_r(x)}$.
Thanks for the comments

I would approach it like this (which is slightly different and you can take it as a hint) : Show that your set $A$ is just a closed ball of radius $r$ around $0$ which has been 'translated' by $K$.

Another way of seeing the closed part is to show that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=d(x,K)$ is a continuous function (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Distance_from_Point_to_Subset_is_Continuous_Function) and then show that $A= f^{-1}((-r,r))$.

For yet another approach, you can express the union as the image of a continuous function $K \times \overline{B_r(0)}$, $(x, y) \mapsto x+y$.

Yes indeed your ways of doing it are a lot smarter than mine, both SeverinSchraven and HackR , DanielSchepler (which I think both you meant the same). I still have difficulties playing with 'constructing' functions.

You have the right idea, I think you just need to be a little more careful with your sequences and subsequences, and which limits are implied by which conditions. For instance, can you really necessarily conclude that $(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ has a limit, given just that $(y_k)_k$ has a limit and $y_k \in \overline{B}_r(x_k)$ for each $k$? Imagine a situation in which $\overline{B}_r(x_1)$ and $\overline{B}_r(x_2)$ overlap, and $(y_k)_k$ converges to some point in the intersection, but as for $(x_k)_k$ we alternately choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ forever.
Here is the beginning of your argument with some more precise wording: let $(y_k)_k$ be a sequence of points in $A = \bigcup_{x\in K}\overline{B}_r(x)$. In other words, for each $k$ there is a point $x_k \in K$ such that $y_k \in \overline{B}_r(x_k)$. We also assume that $(y_k)_k$ has a limit point $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and our goal is to show that $y\in A$.
Now, $(x_k)_k$ forms a sequence is $K$, which is not just closed but also compact. Then by compactness...?
Here is another tip: it might be easier to prove the result by contradiction. Suppose to the contrary $y \notin A$, then what does this mean for $y$ in terms of the points $x\in K$? Furthermore, if $y_k$ converges to $y$ anyway, then...? I haven't thought through all the details entirely, but you might consider this.

You are almost there. Think about how the property that $y\in \overline{B_r(x)}$ is expressed analytically. And moreover, if it is preserved under taking limits.
Good luck!
